# Worklight Polling Adapter - Calling another Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

In Worklight 5.0.6, we have created an eventSource using the following:

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name: 'ReminderSource',
    onUserSubscribe: 'userSubscribeFunc',
    poll: {
        interval: 86400,
        onPoll: 'getReminders'
    }
});
```

The getReminders procedure then calls other HTTP and SQL adapters to determine if we should send a Push Notification.  When we deploy this to our Worklight server, we see the following error any time we try to call one of the procedures in another adapter:

> The resource 'proc:tbl_member.getPreferences' should only be accessed
>   when authenticated in realm 'wl_antiXSRFRealm'.

We've tried using a mobileSecurityTest (which includes the wl_antiXSRFRealm) to protect the eventSource, but we get the same error.  Is there a way to have our polling adapter procedure somehow "log in" to the antiXSRFRealm?

We can't make the other adapter procedures unprotected, because they do need to be protected.

Answer (score 0):

antiXSRF is used for client-server cross scripting attack detection. It doesn't do too much for invocations between adapter procedures. Try creating a custom security test and adding only user realm there, no antiXSRF.

Comment: When we did this, we saw an error message in the logs that the push notification security test requires the antiXSRF realm.  In the meantime, we have worked around this issue by building all the functions needed to complete the adapter process into the single adapter itself.